# error occur after setting class outputdir in build.gradle

Tags: gradle

I want to setting a new dir for compiled java class file when use gradle.
But it never work.
[image]

[image]

```
apply plugin: 'java'

//apply plugin: 'war'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/']
            outputDir = 'WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/'
        }

        resources {
            srcDirs = [ 'src/' ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your text as text. Not as an image.

Comment: @JBNizet I update the config code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gradle > 4. Note for type of the value for `outputDir` property. It should be `File`. Not `String` like in your question's code:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        output.resourcesDir = file('out/res')
        java.outputDir   = file('out/bin')
    }
}
```

see 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html#setOutputDir(java.io.File)

and

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSetOutput.html

Before version 4 gradle was using single output directory for different jvm languages.

So, for gradle < 4:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        output.resourcesDir = file('out/res')
        output.classesDir   = file('out/bin')
    }
}
```

see https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSetOutput.html.